# Removing the first title line from a text file after reading into python

Tags: python, python-2.7, text-files

I have loaded the text file by the following command. I want to remove the first title line from the `contents` that lines has been separated by `\n`. How to do it?

```
txtfile = open(filepath, "rt")
contents = txtfile.read()
contents
'Label  Volume(voxels)SurfArea(mm^2) Eccentricity   Elongation     Orientation    Centroid                      Axes Length                   Bounding Box                  \n  1      148766  ...
```

Second, how to remove the`\n` from the end of each element (i.e., each line) of `contents`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
txtfile = open(filepath, "rt")
txtfile.readline()  # Discard first line
contents = txtfile.read()
```

Comment: `contents.splitlines()` removes the '\n` at the end of each line

Comment: It does, but you didn't include that in your question when I answered it. ;-) It's generally better to ask additional questions as separate SO questions.

Comment: Yes, but I am not able to ask any question because of limitation. `f=contents.splitlines() `, and then `ff=np.vstack(f)`.  the shape of `ff` is (3,1), in which each row has 9 other elemnts (columns). Now I want to choose the 2nd column, however, when I write into a `dataFrame` I still cannot access to each elements.

Answer (score 2):

Using slicing:

file:

```
Label  Volume(voxels)SurfArea(mm^2) Eccentricity   Elongation     Orientation    Centroid                      Axes Length                   Bounding Box                  \n1
148766
```

**Hence**:

```
txtfile = open(filepath, "rt")
contents = txtfile.readlines()[1:]    # skip the first line
print(contents)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
['148766']
```

**EDIT**:

If the text is in a single line, you can convert the list to a string and split() by the separator `\n`:

```
txtfile = open(filepath, "rt")
contents = txtfile.readlines()
print("".join(contents).split(r'\n1')[1:])
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. How to have the rest of files in a numpy array?

Comment: Do you mean the content of the files? Are you trying to extract contents from multiple files?

Comment: No it is the same file, however, I want to have the rest of file (i.e., `contents`) (after removing the first title line) in a numpy array to be able to access specific column. Each line is separated by '\n'.

Comment: Better to ask that as a separate SO question.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
txtfile = open(filepath, "rt")
contents = txtfile.read()
#split it and join only the items after it
after = ''.join(contents.split(r'\n1')[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just skip the header using `next` on the `fd`,

```
>>> with open(filepath, "rt") as textfile:
...    next(textfile)  # Discard first line
...    contents = txtfile.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example this could work:

```
import re
#your code
content = re.sub( ".*?\n1", "", content, 1 ) #Replace the first occurance of "[Anything]\n1" with ""
```